# Difference in variance of factor scores for supplementary and active observations PCA

Tags: variance, pca

I've been trying to find an answer to this but I haven't been successful. I encounter a problem when adding supplementary individuals to PCA. The variance of the factor scores decreases dramatically when adding supplementary observations.

I am doing a PCA in R on genome data. The data table has 1645 rows (individuals) and 23,446 columns (SNPs). I use a subset of 103 rows to do the PCA and then project the remaining individuals on the PCA using the eigenvector matrix.

I first standardize the matrix by subtracting the column means. I also subtract these column means from the columns of the whole sample.
Taking into account that the number of columns largely exceed the number of rows I then perform the Eigen decomposition on $XX^t$ and then multiply the obtained eigenvector matrix by $X^t$ to obtain the Eigenvector/loadings matrix of $X^tX$.

I then multiply the loadings matrix with (1) the matrix of the 'active' individuals, and (2) the complete matrix (the whole sample).

Now my problem: the variance of the factor scores for the 'active' individuals (red) far exceeds the variance of the factor scores for the whole sample. (~ by a factor of 10, variances take values 114 and 12 respectively). I would have expected the variances to be almost the same or rather the variance for the whole sample to be bigger. I've been looking for an explanation for quite a while now and I get the feeling that I am stuck. Anyone can help me out? I highly appreciate any hint!

My Code

```
    # standardize matrix by subtracting comlumn means
    genos100.diff<- apply(genos100, 2, function(x) x-mean(x))       
  

    #subtract same column mean from the whole sample
    
    one <- rep(1, nrow(genos.ctrl))
    colmeans <- colMeans(genos100)
    
    genos.ctrl.diff <- genos.ctrl- one%*%t(colmeans)
    
    #compare variances
    
    apply(genos100.diff[,1:10],2, function(x) var(x))
      
    
    apply(genos.ctrl.diff[,1:10],2, function(x) var(x))
    
    # variances consisent
    ####################
    #compute xxt
    xxt <- genos100.diff%*%t(genos100.diff)
    
    
    # eigendecomposition of xxt
    evv <- eigen(xxt, symmetric=TRUE)
    # 
    # eigenvectors of xxt/scores/ matrix F
    pcs <- evv$vectors[,1:5] # 103 rows
    
    
    
    # get eigenvalues
    evals <- evv$values[1:5]
    
    
    
    #### Get loadings/ pcs of xtx/ Q
    # compute the transform of the eigenvector matrix  Qt and normalize
    
    btr <- diag(1/sqrt(evals))%*%t(pcs)%*%genos100.diff
    
    # apply to active individuals, obtain scores
    
    pcs_active <-genos100.diff%*%t(btr)
    
    # Get scores for supplementary individuals 
    pcs_suppl <- genos.ctrl.diff%*%t(btr)
    
    
    # compute variances of the first principal component
    
    ##                
    var(pcs_active[,1]) # 114.0419
    var(pcs_suppl[,1])  # 12.76595
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not very familiar with R, but from the problem description I do not see anything surprising. You do your PCA on 103 "active" data points and find the first principle component (PC1) that explains most of the variance. This means that when you project your 103 "active" data points onto this PC1 direction you get the largest possible variance $Var(z) = \frac{1}{102}\Sigma_{i=1}^{103} z_i^2 $, where $z_i$ are the projections. Now when you project the whole dataset (1645 data points) onto the same direction, the variance is given by $Var(z) = \frac{1}{1644}\Sigma_{i=1}^{1645} z_i^2$, and this can easily be smaller than before.

I strongly suspect that your "active" PC1 explains very little variance of the "passive" data points. In this case your "passive" data points would have a very different PC1, and PC1 calculated on the whole data set would also be quite different from the one you get from the "active" data points only.

But this is not necessarily so: it can also be that all the "passive" data points are located close to zero, and so don't contribute much to the variance, whereas division by 1644 instead of 102 makes the variance decrease 10-fold.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that! It seems weird to me however because the data points are all coded 0,1,2 , so their all of the same order of magnitude and the variance and means of the columns prior to multiplying with the projection matrix are the same for the active sample and the whole sample. I.e. the active sample actually seems to represent well the whole sample. This is not intuitive for me at all. You don't think there's an error?

Comment: In this case my second explanation is unlikely, and the first one seems to be the most probable. Can't you test it by computing PC1 on the "passive" sample? Then you can directly compare it with the PC1 computed on the "active" sample. Regarding your R code, I cannot say if there are any mistakes, let somebody else check it.

Comment: I calculated the principal components for the whole sample and computed the correlations with the PCS of the active sample. For PC1 it is only $0.074$!
So you think a likely explanation would be that the "active" PC explains very little variance of the "passive" data points? For this data the first principal component actually doesn't explain much of the variance of the dataset (the eigenvalues are almost similar). Could this be a general result for those kind of datasets? Where no principal with a huge discriminative power exists? Thanks for you answers!

Comment: You can test this directly. Compute PC1 for the "passive" dataset and the amount of "passive" variance it explains. Then take your PC1 for the "active" dataset and check the amount of "passive" variance it explains. If there is a large difference, then "active" and "passive" datasets are indeed structured differently. If the amount of variance is comparable, but correlation between these two PCs is very small (as you say), then it probably means that there is not much structure in the datasets, all PCs explain little variance and "active" PC1 can be "passive" PC2 or something like that.

Comment: ok, just to be make sure that I understoodcorrectly. Did you want to say ...(cite: ) Then take your PC1 for the "active" dataset and check the amount of "ACTIVE" variance ? 

This is interesting thank you

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote. The question is how good active PC1 is in explaining passive data set, and is it much worse or approximately equal to passive PC1. But if I were you, I would do all kinds of checks.

Comment: Ok, so allow me the question: How would you do that, check the amount of "passive" variance explained by the "active" PC1?

Comment: I am not sure we are not abusing the comments section by this discussion (StackExchange suggests moving it to chat). Still, to answer your question: well, you project your "passive" dataset onto the "active" PC1 direction (Z=X*W, where X is your dataset and W the PC vector), then you compute the variance var(Z) and then you normalize it by the total variance of the dataset (trace of covariance matrix of X). It is exactly the same procedure you can use to compute the amount of "passive" variance explained by the "passive" PC1, no difference at all (only that it is not given by an eigenvalue).